# Checkbox onchange function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I have a page with a set of checkbox's, that I want to run a Javascript function on when there is a change (I have done something very similar with dropdown's - and that worked)

However with the checkbox's I have three problems:

1. my `onChange` event only runs "sometimes" (you have to change the focus between the different checkbox controls
2. when it does run it is returning the result of the previous checkbox (not the one just clicked on)
3. the jQuery always return the value true

**Checkbox creation**

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("sl-" + row.Id, value, new { onChange = "SuitabilityChecked("+row.Id+", "+key+")"})%>
```

**Javascript**

```
function SuitabilityChecked(providerId, parentRecordId) {
            var params = {};
            params.providerId = providerId;
            params.parentRecordId = parentRecordId;

            var value = $("#sl-" + providerId).val();               
            
            params.value = value;            
            $.getJSON("SuitabilityChecked", params, null);
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers are funny about radio buttons and check boxes and can delay the onchange until focus change. Try adding an onclick event to blur or call the change event directly.

Maybe something like this using jQuery Live (untested, off the top of my head):

```
$(':checkbox').live('click', function() { $(this).change(); });
```

Comment: Ahh! Yes my winforms background stuffed me up there, I changed it to an onclick rather than onchange and the proc fired as I would expect.

The JQuery still always returns true for the value of the checkbox, however

Comment: Doh. Try $("#sl-" + providerId).attr('checked')

Answer (score 0):

What's happening:

1. Checkbox A clicked
2. Checkbox B clicked
3. Checkbox A has lost focus and fires *onChange*

Which makes it seem as if Checkbox B is returning the result of Checkbox A. If you were to press Tab after clicking Checkbox B in this scenario, you'd notice that its *onChange* would fire.